# Charles "SSL Proxying not Enabled for this Host" for android emulator, when it really is

Tags: android, https, android-emulator, charles-proxy

I have configured the proxy settings in my Android Emulator, installed the charles certificate, added all hosts (*:*) in charles ssl proxy settings, and also added the android emulator's address to charles.

[image]

[image]

[image]

so why is it that all of the traffic I see shows up obfuscated / encrypted still?

[image]

[image]